# Show $U_1 \cup U_2=V \implies U_1=V$ or $U_2=V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vectorspace over the field $K$ and $U_1, U_2$ subspaces of $V$.

Show $U_1 \cup U_2 = V \implies U_1=V$ or $U_2=V$

my thoughts:

Let $x_1 \in U_1$ and $x_2 \in U_2$, then $x_1+x_2 \in U_1 \cup U_2$. But this would mean
$x_1+x_2 \in U_2$ or $x_1+x_2 \in U_1$. This would mean $U_1=V$ or $ U_2=V,$ since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are any elements from $U_1 \cup U_2 = V.$

Could someone give me a feedback if its correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original proof is problematic because you go from the statement "for every $x_1,x_2,x_1 + x_2 \in U_1$ or $x_1 + x_2 \in U_2$" to the statement " $x_1 + x_2 \in U_1$ for every $x_1,x_2,$ or $x_1+x_2 \in U_2$ for every $x_1,x_2$" without justification.

Here is an alternative way to construct the proof that you might find helpful.  It suffices to show that $U_1 \cup U_2 = V$ and $V \neq U_1$, then it must hold that $V = U_2$. To that end, suppose (for the purpose of contradication) that there exists an element $x \in U_1 \setminus U_2$.

Comment: Since  $U_1 \cup U_2 = V$, why do you think that "but this would mean
$x_1+x_2 \in U_2$ or $x_1+x_2 \in U_1$" is not justified?

Comment: something like that?
take $x_{1} \in U_{1}$ s.t. $x_{1} \notin U_{2}.$ Take any $x_2 \in U_{2}$ s.t. $x_{2} \notin U_{1}.$ It follows then $x_{1}+x_{2} \notin U_{1}$ and $x_{1}+x_{2} \notin U_{2}.$ This would mean $x_{1}+x_{2} \notin U_{1} \cup U_{2}$, contradiction.

Comment: @HoaL  In your comment above, you just proved, by contradiction, that $U_1 \setminus U_2=\emptyset$ or $U_2 \setminus U_1=\emptyset$. It means $U_1 \subseteq U_2$ or $U_2 \subseteq U_1$.  Since $U_1 \cup U_2 = V $, it follows that $V=U_1$ or $V=U_2$.

Comment: @Ramiro I mean that this statement "$x_1 + x_2 \in U_2$ or $x_1 + x_2 \in U_1$ is not a direct application of definitions, and therefore must be proved.

Comment: got it, thanks for help guys!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here. The question says $U_1 \cup U_2 = V $, and the argument is "$x_1+x_2 \in U_1 \cup U_2$. But this would mean
$x_1+x_2 \in U_2$ or $x_1+x_2 \in U_1$". Why do you say that that the conclusion "But this would mean
$x_1+x_2 \in U_2$ or $x_1+x_2 \in U_1$" is not a direct application of definitions, and therefore must be proved? Isn't it direct from the definition of union that if $v\in V= U_1 \cup U_2$, then $v\in U_1$ or $v\in U_2$?

Comment: @Ramiro Ah, actually you're right. The issue with the original proof is actually the jump from saying "for every $x_1,x_2,x_1 + x_2 \in U_1$ or $x_1 + x_2 \in U_2$" to saying " $x_1 + x_2 \in U_1$ for every $x_1,x_2$ or $x_1+x_2 \in U_2$ for every $x_1,x_2$."

Answer (score 2):

**Completely wrong.**

**Proof** Let $U_1\neq V$, then there is $v_0\in V\smallsetminus U_1$. But $U_2\cup U_1=V$ gives $v_0\in U_2\dots (1)$.

Let $v\in V$.

If $v\notin U_1$ then $v\in U_2$.

Otherwise if $v\in U_1$ then $v+v_0\notin U_1$ (since $v_0\notin U_1$). Thus $v+v_0\in U_2$. Hence from $(1)$ this implies $v\in U_2$.

Thus $V\subseteq U_2\implies V=U_2$. Hence it is proved.

Comment: I think you meant to write "Let $v\in V$. Then $v\in U_2$" (it is what you actually proved).  On the other hand, since $U_1 \cup U_2 = V $, the statement "Let $v\in V$. Then $v\notin U_1\implies v\in U_2$" is trivial.

Comment: Yes, I meant to prove it and I proved. I showed, irrespective of $v$ is in $U_1$ or not, $v\in V\implies v\in U_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_1\in U_1$ but $x_2\notin U_1$ then we know $x_1+x_2\notin U_1$, 
similarly if $x_1\notin U_2$ but $x_2\in U_2$ then we know $x_1+x_2\notin U_2$,
So if $x_1,x_2$ satisfying above condition then $x_1+x_2\notin U_1\cup U_2$

So if $U_1,U_2$ both are proper subspaces/subgroups then we will always find $x_1,x_2$ satisfying above condition, and $x_1+x_2\notin U_1\cup U_2$. (neglecting the trivial case when either $U_1$ or $U_2$ is subgroup of the other and both are proper subgroups)

If $U_1\cup U_2=V$ then there is no such $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1\in U_1,x_1\notin U_2,x_2\notin U_1,x_2\in U_2$) . With both $U_1,U_2$ being proper subgroups/subspaces,this is not possible; so at least one of them is $V$.